# specifying different images in xCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

In xCode when I specify iPad images I can use syntax like: `image~ipad.png`, `image~ipad@2x.png`, etc.

Is there any special designators for iPhone?  For example, `iPhone 5 - 640x1136`, `iPhone 4/4s - 640x960` and `iPhone - 320x480.`

If not, what is the best way to have different images?  Do I need to do this checking in my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new feature introduced in xcode 5 to manage images in your iOS app in better way. That is Asset catalogs. Learn more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) Let me know if more info needed. No need to perform any check in code btw :)

Comment: Great thanks, that will work perfect!!  One question, how do you recommend adding jpg's?

Comment: For jpg & other formats, look at [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785946/how-can-i-add-jpegs-to-an-asset-catalog-in-xcode)