# iOS: Failed to load Asset Catalog JPEG images

Tags: ios8, xcode6

According to WWDC 2014, Asset Catalogs support JPEG images format. I added a JPEG image to my asset catalog, and referenced this image in my storyboard. However, the image just appears white/blank.

I have tried the suggestions in "[How can I add JPEGs to an asset catalog in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785946/how-can-i-add-jpegs-to-an-asset-catalog-in-xcode)", the problem still exists.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set '*Render As..*' option for this image to '*Always Original*' in the right panel of asset catalog editor?