# Impossible to load an image from xcassets on iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, xcasset

I got several images stored in my `Images.xcassets` that I load both through code and Interface Buider. However the iOS 9 update broke everything : the images are not showing neither when loaded from code or IB.

Everything was working fine except that images dont load up anymore.

Say I have an image named `Image` in my `.xcassets`. On iOS 8,

```
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"]
```

returned a valid pointer, but it returns `nil` on iOS 9. The same thing goes on in Interface Builder : all `UIImageView` that are set from IB are empty.

There are two exceptions though : two **small** (48x48) images do indeed load correctly. I noticed they both are compiled into `Assets.car`, all the others are sitting as pngs and jpegs in the main directory ... But the configuration is the *same* far all the images.

This problem didn't exist on iOS 8.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that I was using JPEGs.
It looks like Xcode 7 now requires the `Render As` options set to `Original Image` though Xcode 6.1 was supposed to *also* require this option (from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785946/how-can-i-add-jpegs-to-an-asset-catalog-in-xcode)). However it worked before without it ... (I started the project on Xcode 6.1).

The solution was to change the `Render As` option from `Default` to `Original` :

[image]